# How to map a standard field like phone to custom field in opportunity to a custom field

Tags: apex, community, leads, lead-conversion

I'm new to sfdc.In my organization i tried to map phone standard field in lead to opportunity custom field.But i didn't get mapping field in map fields.I also create a formula field and tried to do mapping with that field.But i didn't get my custom field in that section.Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.And in lead field some data is available.

Comment: you should be able to map custom formula fields on Lead to custom Oppo fields of the same type. Please be more specific

Comment: I want to map a standard field called phone in lead object to map to a custom field in opportunity..@crop1645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do this

1. Create a custom text formula field on Lead `Phone as Text`. The formula is simply `Phone`.
2. Map this field in Lead Field Mapping to a custom Opportunity field (also of type text)

You can't map fields from Lead of type X to an Opportunity field of some different type.  And, you can't create formula fields of type Phone.

Should you absolutely have to have a field on Opportunity of type Phone, you'll need to

1. Create a custom (non-formula) field of type Phone on Lead
2. Create a workflow or process that on create and every edit, does a field update from `Lead.Phone` to `Lead.PhoneCustom__c`
3. Create a custom field of type Phone on Opportunity
4. Lead field map `Lead.PhoneCustom__c` to `Opportunity.Phone__c`

Comment: Already i had created a new custom text field in lead and created a workflow based on lead status every time edited it works fine and i can map easily but is it best practice to do so because so many times lead status has changed every time workflow will fire right even unnecessarily.is there any other way to do so.@crop1645

Comment: The options I outlined above are the only ways point-and-click I know of (plus Blair's answer). Otherwise, you end up with  trigger work to do the mapping yourself from the convertedLead.  I wouldn't worry about the overhead of the workflow

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map standard fields but you could build a process to insert that value into opportunity using [Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lead_conversion_mapping.htm&language=en).

1. Select "Lead" as the object.
2. For the criteria select the "Converted" field and make it equal to true. You can also define more criteria as you see fit.
3. Then go under Create >Flows and click on "New".
4. Add a "Record Update" element.
5. Name it and select the object you want to update "Opportunity".
6. Select any criteria you have for the records and then choose the field.
7. Set the field you want to map to another value.
8. Create a new sobject variable choosing "Lead" as the object.
9. Then select the field you would want the opportunity field to match.
10. Select the element as the starting element.
11. Go back to the process and click on immediate actions.
12. Choose the flow option and add the flow.
13. Set the flow variable, save, and activate.

Comment: Can you add some detail around how you would use `Process Builder`? This answer is likely to get flagged for deletion as it stands, because it is very short and contains little more than a link.

Comment: can you share or show create a process means like define criteria and action how to specify a condition lead is converted. @Blair Kristin